# Can't get a simple jquery ajaxoncomplete to work?

Tags: ajax, jquery

Where do i go wrong?

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
  //always focus on input field
  //$('#documentID').focus();
  $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(){
        var docID =  $('#documentID').val();
       alert("test "+docID);
       var lookupData = new Array();
  $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "lookup.php",
            data: {documentID: docID},
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(msg){ 
alert(msg);//shows Wrong as expected
            //do stuff after the AJAX calls successfully completes
             $("#note").ajaxComplete(function(){
                        if(msg == "Wrong") 
                        {
                            result = 'Not so OK';   
                            $('#logo_header').hide();//just to test things  
                       }
                        else
                        {
                            result = 'OK lookup';
                            lookuData = msg;//populate all data
                        }
                        $(this).html(result);

                    });//#end ajaxComplete and populate note
            }//#end success

        });//#end AJAX
  })//#end function

});
```

And lookup.php returns wrong or ok (for testing purpose), but i can't get div #note to show the message and the div logo_header doesn't hide.

Any info?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `$("#note")` is not processing the ajax call, therefore it is never hitting the `if (msg == "wrong")` statement.

Try removing `$("#note").ajaxComplete`

And have:

```
success: function(msg){ 
alert(msg);//shows Wrong as expected
        //do stuff after the AJAX calls successfully completes
                    if(msg == "Wrong") 
                    {
                        result = 'Not so OK';   
                        $('#logo_header').hide();//just to test things  
                   }
                    else
                    {
                        result = 'OK lookup';
                        lookuData = msg;//populate all data
                    }
                    $(this).html(result);

        }//#end
```

Answer (score 0):

Tx, guys will look into your suggestions, but i think i found the problem. I am using twitter bootstrap with the default jquery src

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js
```

and when i use this jquery source

```
<script src="./site/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3"></script>
```

the ajaxComplete seems to work correctly.

So my conclusion jQuery 1.9.1 doesn't support ajaxComplete vs jQuery 1.8.3 does????

@Aspiring Aqib, this is a simple test. Next step is to return an array from lookup.php (json). So i think i need to make a difference in which msg/data is being return.